# How to set button value in loop in Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am doing very simple application using Spring and Thymeleaf. I have a list of categories on one page and I would like to go to another page after clicking on one of the links. But the pages will be very similar, so I would like to do a template and I need to send to controller the name of choosen category. I thought that I can have buttons as links and I tried to send button value to the controller, but I cannot do it in a loop. When I assignt "hard tekst" to the value it is ok, but when I want to assign current value in a loop in the controller I have ${category.name} not for example "category 1".

Here is a part of my code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr th:each="category:  ${categories}">
       <td>
          <form action="/categoryPage" method="post">
              <button name="categoryName"  value="${category.name}">
                   <span th:text="${category.name}"></span>
              </button>
          </form>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I am checking the value in this way:

```
@PostMapping("/categoryPage")
@ResponseBody
public String getCategory (@RequestParam String categoryName)
{
    //.........
    return categoryName;
}
```

I would like to ask you how to solve this problem. Maybe there is a better way to do it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you are using Thymeleaf then you need your action to be `th:action="@{/categoryPage}"`. Also your button value should be `th:value="${category.name}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use `POST` and `form` to solve the initial issue. Your method is named `getCategory` so I assume that it will return a new category page => request will be safe and idempotent => GET is the way to go.

Another suggestion is to remove form and button and simply have links elements.

```
<tr th:each="category:  ${categories}">
   <td>
      <a th:href="@{/categoryPage(categoryName=${category.name})}" th:text="${category.name}" class="button"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

You can add to this element css class to make it look and feel like a button. If you are using bootstrap you can check the official [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/). 
A simple example is:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" th:href=../>
```